# How to create android apps using Html and maintain those html pages using a management system?

Tags: android, html

I want to know whether is it possible that if i create an android app using html, then later if i want to update the pages of that app i can do it from an online resource and not give an apk update notification to the user.

Is something like that even possible?? Something BookMyShow app where we never get an update and the pages are updated automatically.

Please Help! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement webview may be useful... create and host your web pages on the server and in webview use url of your website... and make sure that your website design is responsive... by using this u can make changes to pages without new updates to apk